# jQuery append browser compatibility

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following function that can be used for processing an AJAX request.  In this case, I want to append the result to whatever jQuery object I pass in.

```
function GetAppendURLforjQobjwData(url, jQobj, args, showload) {
    if (showload) {
        jQobj.append("<div class='tempload'><p>Please wait for page to load!</p><img src='/NTMPNGServices/images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Wait' /></div>");
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: args,
        success: function(result) {
            jQuery(".tempload").remove();
            jQobj.append(result);
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax itself works great.  When I run this in Firefox, everything works exactly as expected.  If `showload` is true, then immediately a div pops up with the gif image.  Once the request has been processed, the gif is removed and the result is appended correctly.

The problem is that this does not work in Chrome or IE.  The ajax part is fine in that the result eventually shows up, but the user has no feedback to tell them that something is happening.

If I completely take out `jQuery.ajax({...` then the gif appears just fine in all browsers.  Or if I remove `jQuery(".tempload").remove();` then I get both the gif and the result from the ajax request.

Why will my load screen not show up temporarily like it should in Chrome and IE??

Comment: Is there any error in the developer log?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors anywhere, unless I'm not looking in the right places.  Why the downvote??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting `async: false` in your ajax request, which freezes the javascript engine until you get the response..

Remove it, and (except something terrible happens) never use it again..

Comment: It is okay that the javascript engine is frozen, because it should have already executed the line that shows the gif image.  The behavior that I want is that it shows the gif and the wait message until the result comes back.  Changing the async setting did not have any effect on my problem.  Further, why would it work in Firefox if this was the problem?

Comment: After reading some more about this issue and the async: false setting, I tried it again.  I must not have cleared the cache last time, which was why it didn't change anything then.  But for this case, it does indeed solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess `async: false` also kind of blocks the whole browser process (or thread, it doesn't relly matters). Maybe Firefox deprecated synchronous requests and ignores your settings.. It's all about implementations..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success: function(result) 
{
      jQobj.append(result);
      jQuery(".tempload").remove();
}
```

I think that the jquery selector did not find the ".tempload" so there is an error and the next line won't work

Comment: I tried your suggestion just to be certain, but it did not make any difference.  The problem is not that the next line isn't working.  jQobj.append(result); works just fine.  The problem is that the user can't see that it is working.